# How do I turn on multi-CPU/Core C++ compiles in the Visual Studio IDE (2008)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, multicore

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project that has support for using multiple CPUs/cores when compiling.  In the VCPROJ file I see this:

```
<Tool
    Name="VCCLCompilerTool"
    AdditionalOptions="/MP"
    ...
```

I can't find where that was turned added via the IDE and I want to set up another project that uses all of my cores during compilation.

I found tons of references to the [MSDN /MP page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx) but that is for using the command line; I have yet to find any references to setting that with the IDE.  How do I do that?

EDIT: To clarify, the two projects are completely separate and are not in the same VCPROJ file.  I wanted to turn on support for multiple cores during the C++ compilation phase.

Comment: Useful to know as well - the /MP option also works on Visual Studio 2005.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To enable /MP option you could add it to `Project Settings->C/C++->Command Line|Additional options`. This is the only way to switch it on in vcproj.

[image]

Comment: This worked.  As a test I jammed it into the VCPROJ directly.  After seeing your post, I added it to the section you show above -- it's exactly the same thing.

Comment: The difference between this and the Build-And-Run option is that /MP allows MULTIPLE FILES from ONE project to compile in parallel, while the build-and-run option allows MULTIPLE PROJECTS to build at the same time.  The two options are orthogonal.

Comment: You may also need to disable the /Gm option, which enables minimal rebuild, under Code Generation.

Comment: To get all the CPU meters in Task Manager dancing at once, you might need to hardcode the number.  For example, on a 6-core i5, /MP12 instead of just /MP.  This depends on hyperthreading settings, etc.

Comment: @metal, so I have to trade off multi-core compilation of the entire project with single-core compilation of the minimum rebuild..? I'm either wasting cores or I'm doing an incredibly inefficient build.. :/

Answer (score 5):

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > maximum number of parallel project builds

Comment: Both my projects have "maximum number of parallel project builds" set to 2 (which is correct) but the original project shows the /MP switch and my new project doesn't.  When I compile both projects, the original is definitely using multiple cores while the new one is not.

Comment: You will not switch on /MP build via that settings. This option will enable parallel builds of several projects in one solution, not several files in one project. This option suitable only for big solutions.