# Can qmake configure command line options in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qmake

I am interested in using `/MP` as a command line option in each Visual Studio project I create with qmake (because this greatly speeds compilation) - see [here for description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422601/how-do-i-turn-on-multi-cpu-core-c-compiles-in-the-visual-studio-ide-2008).

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to set this in a Qt .pro file - or if it is even possible.

Is it possible to set command line flags (as in the linked question) for qmake to recognize and add to Visual Studio projects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /MP
```

It seems to be working - setting that and running `qmake -tp vc` sets the MP flag in compiler's options.